# How to include SPACEBAR click on bash script to unpause a rosbag?

Tags: bash, ros

I have a script that needs to start a few ros nodes including a rosbag. Within those nodes, I need to start the rosbag with the --pause flag. Normally, I would need to press the spacebar to unpause the bag and get my script running after ~5 second. My question is, how can I get this done on a bash script?

I have tried a few different things like:
... &
(sleep 5; echo -e ' ';) & ...

or echo '\s' or echo '\r'. I know the echo command happens but that doesn't quite give the signal to the bag to start playing (unpause). If I press the spacebar even while using the script, the bag will play. How can I recreate this spacebar from my bash script?

Comment: correction: echo -e '\s' or echo -e '\r'. echo doesnt seem to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

solved this with:

xte 'key space'

Comment: This would require that you are running X, but you didn't specify an operating environment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`rosbag play` creates a node with a service that can be called to pause/play the bag file. Once you spin everything up in 'pause' mode, you can use your sleep and then a `rosservice call ...` to start the bag play.

By default, the bag play is an anonymous node. You can name it with the appropriate argument or name it in a launch file. This can also be leveraged to control your bag play from another script/program